# Add health.html check endpoint to Angular application

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-ui-router, openshift, angular-routing

I need to add healthcheck endpoint to my angular application using health.html, which should respond with HTTP 200 and the 'Healthy' string.

I already defined port and path regarding readinessProbe, and livenessProbe in my deployment template.

Create a health.html file ('Health' word inside the file) and place it near the index.html file.

Do I need to create a route for this? what steps am I still missing here?

in the terminal, I want to test.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/health.html
```

Comment: is there any container that is serving angular application as static or maybe server side rendering under openshift ?

Comment: yes, serving angular app as static

Comment: what is insise of that container? nginx?

Comment: @Cpui Did you fix above issue?

Comment: @KapilSoni i just added health.html inside app folder. added Healthy word inside html file

Comment: @Cpui I have fixed above issue did you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me if your app is deployed like /ui you can you change according to path and /health is same

> ```
> //For test message
> location /ui/health/ {
>     return 200 'Healthy';
> }
>
> //For Load website use below
> location /ui/health/ {
>    try_files $uri $uri/ /ui/health/index.html;
> }
> ```